# Is it possible to make App_GlobalResources a virtual directory?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, virtual-directory

Bad design aside, I have a web application that has dependencies on several folders in another web application.
I've successfully made virtual directories for bin, several folders under App_Code folder, but I'm having trouble with creating a virtual directory for App_GlobalResources.  I'm getting

> "App_GlobalResources maps to a
>   directory outside this application"

error when building my app.

*NOTE* I do not have the trailing slash at the end of the directory in IIS.
My environment is Windows Server 2003 32 bit, Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be surprised if this worked as I believe that .NET loads up non-compiled resource files using physical (but relative) paths. So, my first instinct would be to say that you cannot remap the resource folders using virtual paths. However, you could play other tricks like using an NTFS junction point. I would highly, highly recommend against this as you will shock the hell out the person that discovers this solution but in theory it would let you map App_GlobalResources to something else.

Comment: @Dave Harding - That's a typo on my part. It should be a *NTFS* junction point. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point

Comment: @Dave Harding - A junction point basically remaps a folder to point to another folder. From the perspective of the file system (i.e. explorer), it doesn't know that the folder points somewhere else.

Comment: Hmmm, probably not a good idea.  I'm only trying to prevent repetition and having to keep track of updating more than one location when the .resx file changes.  If I don't get any other answers, I'll award you the answer.  Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Dave Harding - Is it that a file would only change via source control? If so, most source code control systems have the ability to create shared folders.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried them, but asp.net lets you write your own custom resource providers.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx is a start, with a databased example.